# Importing Function with JEST + JSDOM

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, jsdom

I want to test function which manipulate my DOM. Thus I use jsdom + jest.

If I import the function, then the DOM loads not correctly and I receive a TypeError. The Error tells my that an element is not defined. Which would be defined in the beginning of my main.js.

If I don't import the function, then I could not run the test, because the function is not defined.

**the test.js:**

```
const { JSDOM,VirtualConsole} = require('jsdom')

//the function i want to import
const round = require("./main.js").round;

describe('calculate', () => {
    let dom
    let document

    //load the DOM before all tests
    beforeAll(async () => {
        dom = await initDom('index.html')
        document = dom.window.document
    })

    //my test to test the "round"-function
    test(`round`, () => {
        expect(round(0.12345)).toEqual(0.12)
    })
})
```

**important part of main.js:**

```
 module.exports = {
    round: round,
}

const pongbar_right = document.getElementById("pongbar_right");
pongbar_right.style.top = 250;
-> here is be the Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
```

**initDom:**

```
const {JSDOM, VirtualConsole}  = require('jsdom')

global.initDom = (htmlFile) => {
    const virtualConsole = new VirtualConsole();
    virtualConsole.on('log', (...args) => {console.log(`&${args}`)})
    return JSDOM.fromFile(htmlFile, {
        resources: 'usable',
        runScripts: "outside-only",
        virtualConsole
    })
}
```

Comment: can you provide the stacktrace of the error - message ?

Comment: @MatthiasGwiozda No, i don't know what this is honestly.

Comment: Just make a screenshot of the error - Message an post it here please